# Warning: Type created with compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle, object, warnings

Type is created but i wanna the warning is about. If you can help

```
SQL> create type missions_type under mission_type;
2  /

Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

SQL> Warning: Type created with compilation errors.
```

Comment: What did `show errors` say?

Comment: SQL> show errors

Errors for TYPE MISSIONS_TYPE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/38     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
         one of the following:
         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last statement seems to be incomplete. Here's an example which *compiles*; see if it helps (you'll certainly have to modify it).

```
SQL> create or replace type intervenant_type as object (id number);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type mission_type as object
  2  ( code varchar(30),
  3   intitule varchar(50),
  4   nbJours number,
  5   Ref_intervenant ref intervenant_type )
  6   not final;
  7  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type missions_type under mission_type (id number);
  2  /                                                       -----------
                                                  This is what you are missing
Type created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is compulsory to add 'NOT FINAL' to let subtypes created

SQL> create type mission_type(id number(3)) NOT FINAL;
2  /
Type created.
SQL> create missions_type under mission_type(code varchar(10));
2 /
Type created.

also you can put any attributes of your choice in the type.